# How to make classic jQuery parallax more smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I have a classic jQuery parallax set up like this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  parallax();
});

var offset;

$(document).ready(function(){
  var p = $( ".content" );
  var offset = p.offset();
  var offset = offset.top;
});

function parallax() {
  render($(document).scrollTop());
}

function render(ev) {
  var t = ev;
  var y = Math.round(t * .25);
  $('.content').css('bottom', - y - 100 + 'px');
}
```

Is there a way to make it somehow more smooth?

Comment: Did you try a *smooth scrollbars* plugin like https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar ?

Comment: You could look at implementing`scroll-behavior` where available to the browser, and use something like the above as a fallback for browsers which don't yet support it.

Comment: Use css-property `transition` and also you need some freezer, that will be launch scroll handler once at 300ms for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to add `transition` on the `.content` element.

```
.content{
  transition: bottom 0.3s linear;
}
```

You will need to fire the parallax function with the same interval as you specify on the transition.

Try something like this to fire your parallax function at the same interval:

```
var interval;
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  //prevent from stopping the interval
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  //execute parallax every 300ms => same as transition
  if(!interval){
    parallax();
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      parallax();
    }, 300);
  }

  //stops the interval after you stopped scrolling for x amount of time
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please elaborate how would you fire the renderer function you are talking about? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Zammy, this is a really nice solution that actually works :)